# Aggregation with priority on Y values with respect to N values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have data like

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Y |
| 1 | N |
| 2 | N |
| 3 | Y |
| 4 | Y |
| 4 | N |

output required

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Y |
| 2 | N |
| 3 | Y |
| 4 | Y |

I need to print a value if customer id 1 has two value y and N then print Y when customer 2 has value N then print N in SQL query.

Comment: So what is your question here? What is stopping you getting the data set you want? What is the logic for the data set you want?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
select id , max(value) as value 
from tablename
group by id
```